# Why is the generated query from LinQ different if I build the where-clause dynamically for a COUNT()?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, count

I want to count rows for a certain query for which I build the `WHERE`-clause dynamically.

What excited me was the difference I saw when building this in two different ways.

### Try 1

```
int resultsCount = context.MyView.Where(x => x.Id > 100000).Count();
```

in the profiler I see, that the following query is being executed:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM (SELECT 
      [MyView].[Id] AS [Id], 
      [MyView].[EventTypeId] AS [EventTypeId], 
      [MyView].[EventSourceId] AS [EventSourceId], 
      [MyView].[TraceLevelId] AS [TraceLevelId], 
      [MyView].[TimeCreated] AS [TimeCreated], 
      [MyView].[Data1MaxStr] AS [Data1MaxStr]
      FROM [dbo].[MyView] AS [MyView]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] > 100000
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

### Try 2

But I have to check for multiple conditions and not all of them need to be met for every execution. So I tried building the `WHERE`-clause for my `COUNT` dynamically (referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880931/linq-dynamic-where-count)):

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyView), "x");
Expression<Func<MyView, bool>> check1 = x => x.Id > 100000;
Expression expression = Expression.Constant(true);
expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, Expression.Invoke(check1, parameter));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyView, bool>>(expression, parameter);

int resultsCount = context.MyView.Where(lambda.Compile()).Count();
```

I would expect to see the same or at least a similar query being executed, but instead I see the following in the profiler:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[EventTypeId] AS [EventTypeId], 
[Extent1].[EventSourceId] AS [EventSourceId], 
[Extent1].[TraceLevelId] AS [TraceLevelId], 
[Extent1].[TimeCreated] AS [TimeCreated], 
[Extent1].[Data1MaxStr] AS [Data1MaxStr]
FROM (SELECT 
      [MyView].[Id] AS [Id], 
      [MyView].[EventTypeId] AS [EventTypeId], 
      [MyView].[EventSourceId] AS [EventSourceId], 
      [MyView].[TraceLevelId] AS [TraceLevelId], 
      [MyView].[TimeCreated] AS [TimeCreated], 
      [MyView].[Data1MaxStr] AS [Data1MaxStr]
      FROM [dbo].[MyView] AS [MyView]) AS [Extent1]
```

The value of `resultsCount` however is the same, but why are those queries so different and where does LinQ get the `COUNT` for the second query, because I do not see any `COUNT` being selected?

Can someone tell me how I can force a query similar to the first but still build my `WHERE`-clause dynamically?

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: most probably on Try2 you should include counting into the expression bulding before it is compiled

Comment: how would I do that, I only know how to append `COUNT` to a query for example instead of a `SELECT`

Comment: line `expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, Expression.Invoke(check1, parameter));` was missing updated it

Comment: Expression<Func<IEnumerable<MyView>, long>> countExpression = x => x.Count(); and then use as in the example about. Probably smth like this?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand, where should that `countExpression` go? I cannot include it into the `WHERE` with `AndAlso`, can I? It probably would have to substitute the `Count()`-call I am currently using, right? But how?

Comment: Could you try `context.MyView.Count(lambda.Compile())` instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38348/discussion-between-drcopypaste-and-yurii-hohan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `Compile` on your expression.

This transforms it from an `Expression<Func<MyView, bool>>` into a `Func<MyView, bool>`.  Since it's just a delegate, and not an `Expression`, it no longer matches the signature for the `IQueryable` overload of `Where`, it only matches the `IEnumerable` overload.

This means that the query isn't translated into SQL; you are querying the data with no filtering at all, and then doing the filtering in LINQ to objects on the client side.

It's important that you *not* compile the lambda if you want the query to be translated into SQL by the query provider.

Comment: thank you for the discussion in chat, the solution was to simply take the highest voted answer from the post i linked (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13881087/2186023) :D